# Chrome developer tools not loading @media queries when switching to device view

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I have this @media query inside my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

/* some styles*/

} /*end @media 767s*/
```

When I manually resize the page, it switch to the responsive layout when it hits the 767px break point.

However, when I select any device layout from the Chrome's dropdown

[image: Chrome's dropdown]

the default page is loaded instead of the media query, even if the device's width is smaller than the 767px break point. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check once again open bracket and close bracket

Comment: Check if you have the correct meta settings in the head of your document: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

Comment: Have you added viewport or any link where we can review and help you?

Comment: Thanks to @Gerard the page is now working. Wondering if that meta tag is necessary to load the media query on the devices too or its only required for Chrome developer tools.

Comment: @MatteoBoscolo is needed for devices also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```